# как на круговой диаграмме поменять цвет секторов python

Tags: python

как на такой диаграмме задать цвет секторов и можно ли подписать эти сектора, например вместо градусов поставить название сектора?

```
N = 8
theta1 = np.arange(0.,2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi / N)
radii1 = np.array([v,sv,s,sz,z,uz,u,uv])
plt.axes([0.045, 0.045, 0.95, 0.95], polar=True)
bars1 = plt.bar(theta1, radii1, width=(2*np.pi/N), bottom=0.0)
plt.show()
```

[image: диаграмма]

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Где код? По фотографии не лечим.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте свою (или используйте встроенную) цветовую карту и используйте параметр `color`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 8
theta1 = np.arange(0.,2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi / N)
#radii1 = np.array([v,sv,s,sz,z,uz,u,uv])
radii1 = np.array([1,3,7,2,5,8,1,4])
plt.axes([0.045, 0.045, 0.95, 0.95], polar=True)
cmap = plt.get_cmap("rainbow")
bars1 = plt.bar(theta1, radii1, width=(2*np.pi/N), bottom=0.0, color = cmap(radii1*10) )
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]